# How can I change the layout color of a ggplot with scale_y_break?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggboxplot

[image: ggboxplot with axis break]

Hi, I plan to plot a black background boxplot with the ggplot function via the configuration of plot. background. The scale_y_break() has been adopted to segment the y-axis. However, the final plot remained a huge white broader, and nothing can be removed.

It would be great if somebody could provide a hint with me. The following was my coding in R.

```
thickbox <- ggboxplot(df_data,x="Yasix",y="Thickness", fill = "Status.y", shape= "Status.y", width = 0.9,  color = "white")+
  scale_y_break(c(620,3700),scales = 1)+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 2,colour = "white"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 2,colour ="white"),
        axis.ticks.length=unit(0.4, "cm"),
        prism.ticks.length.y = unit(0.12, "cm"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 20, color = "white", face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold",colour = "black"),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold",hjust = 0.5,colour = "white"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=28, face = "bold",colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y.right = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size=12),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
        plot.background=element_rect(fill = "black"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
        legend.text = element_text(colour = 'white'),
        legend.title = element_text(colour = "white"))

thickbox
```

- To change the plot.margin via theme() → fail
- To configure the par(bg="black") → fail
- To set the rect = element_rect(fill="black") → fail
- The white broader was the area of the plot title and axis title, as following

[image]

Comment: It seems you are looking for `theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'))`

Comment: I used it but nothing changed

Comment: Yes, you're right. See my explanation and work-around below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the mechanics of `ggbreak`, it produces a special class of object that is only converted into a ggplot when you print it. The layers in the ggplot it produces are not true geom layers, but actually grob layers (i.e. pictures) of two ggplots stitched together. The theme specification you pass applies to the two inset ggplots, but *not* to the resulting ggplot object. The resulting ggplot object has its own theme specification, which only inherits some of the theme elements of the subplots.

The bottom line is that we need to do something like:

```r
print(thickbox) + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', color = 'black'),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', color = 'black'),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = 'black', linewidth = 5, 
                                    fill = NA),
        axis.line = element_line(color = 'black', linewidth = 2))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

There was no data in the question, so I had to create my own with similar values:

```r
set.seed(1)

df_data <- data.frame(Yasix = c(rep(c(-20, 30, 80, 110, 150, 200, 250), 
                                    times = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 5))),
                      Thickness = rnorm(56, mean = rep(c(560, 3750, 560, 3750, 
                                        560, 560, 3750),
                                        times = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 5)), 
                                        sd = 20),
                      Status.y = rep(c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
                                     times = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 5)))
```